# Ring Network random errors - unmanaged switches troubleshooting?

Tags: network

I have a ring network comprised of primary network , and secondary network, 5 PCs connected to it, another 20 controllers and 2 PLCs.

The network is made with Phoenix Contact switches,  about 30 PCs , only 2 are managed.

I`m getting random primary network errors from time to time, especially after I get Modbus alarms from the PLCs.  However the PLCs are connected to different switches in different locations, on primary network.

Any idea how to troubleshoot the communication issue in this time of network?
As I visually checked all switches, they are all indicating communication. After I reboot all primary network switches, it is working fine for a couple of hours, then again I have primary network errors related to all controllers  on the computers.

As per vendor support, they recommend upgrade of the network to all managed switches, which is pretty expensive.
Another thing that they advised is to split the ring by disconnecting primary and secondary network ends.

Any idea how can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Rings with Ethernet switches are generally not advised. Ethernet works best in a tree. Please add a comprehensible description of your network - a diagram, make and models of the switches and their configurations (as text using the editor's `{}` function).

Answer (score 1):

This will be challenging on unmanaged switches, but you might be able to isolate the issue:

From a PC attached to the network, run continuous pings to 1 device (PLC or PC) attached to each switch.

When you next get the comms loss error, check the output of your pings to confirm which devices went down, and which stayed up.  This might point you to the location of the failure and you can start replacing patch leads/fibre cables.

Being a ring network, there must be a ring control protocol running on one of your managed switches - check the logs on these to see if there are any hints as to the MAC address of the switch that detected the error.